# Rails is not picking up my current postgres version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, macos

I stumbled upon following issue. I've upgraded my postgres to version @13 by running `brew install postgresql@13` - this installed version 13.8. I then added paths to my `~/.zshrc` (for compilers too).

Then I run `source ~/.zshrc`, even restarted the whole terminal and restarted my laptop. If I check my postgres version, it's `13.8` but whenever I run any of the rails commands within my project, and then double check it by running `rails c` & `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value('SELECT version()')` it shows the old `PostgreSQL 10.22` version, so obviously my rails is not picking up the current PG version.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bbr5.png)

Do you have any idea what am I missing?

Best,
Martin

Comment: Did you restart your computer after installing the new version? And did you double-check in your `config/database.yml` that Ruby on Rails is connecting to the exact same PostgreSQL instance you are expecting?

Comment: @spickermann yeah, I've restarted the computer after upgrading the version. Actually, I was able to resolve the whole issue by starting different version of postgres by using `brew services`. I noticed the diff when using `psql postgres` - it has shown that the PostgreSQL was indeed 13.8 but the server was still using version 10.22. So the issue wasn't Rails related in the end, rather the version of the instance running locally.